# prove that $U ⊕U_{(2 1)} = U ⊕U_{(3 1)}$

Tags: group-theory

Let U be the submodule of the group algebra $ℂ[S_3]$ generated by

$u_1 := 1−(2 1) + (3 2)−(3 1 2)$

For all $τ ∈ S_3$, let $U_τ$
:= {$τuτ^{-1} ∈ ℂ[S_n] | u ∈ U$}

How would I prove that $U ⊕U_{(2 1)} = U ⊕U_{(3 1)}$ but

$U_{(2 1)} ≠ U_{(3 1)}$

I have no idea how to go about doing this and I don't really know what the direct sum means in this example. Any help would be great!

Comment: The direct sums just mean just means that: $U\cap U_{(21)}=0$ and $U\cap U_{(31)}=0$. The equality means that any element of the form $x+y$, with $x\in U$ and $y\in U_{(21)}$ may be written (in a unique way since the sum is direct) $x'+y'$ with $x'\in U$ and $y'\in U_{(31)}$.